# Unable to find name property

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am having issue trying to get a checkbox on a datatables.js row in one of two situations.

With the code below chkCtrl.name is undefined in the handler function.

```
$("table#tblAssays tbody tr").each(function (index) {
        if ($.trim($(this).find('td:eq(9)').text()) == todayDOW) 
        {
            var chkCtrl = $(this).find("td input:checkbox");
            HandleCheckedChanged(chkCtrl);
        }
```

But if I handle the click event as below this.name returns a value

```
 $("#tblAssays").on("click", "tbody td input:checkbox", function () {
    HandleCheckedChanged(this);
```

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you are resolving to the element and not just trying to get .name from the jQuery object?

Comment: Looks like the Element is not present on the DOM when you assign the handler.. Event delegation in the second case seems to have solved the problem

Comment: where is todayDOW defined?? if it isn't did you mean "todayDOW"  ?

Comment: without seeing sequence of your code and datatables code, and seeing how table is populated it is anyone's guess what the issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).find("td input:checkbox")` returns a jQuery object, which has no name property, whereas `this` within the click handler function refers to a DOM object, which does have a name property.

Try `HandleCheckedChanged(chkCtrl[0]);` instead.

Comment: Thanks dgvid.  Changing to chkCtrl[0] returned the dom object and everthing is working.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you are passing in a jQuery object reference to the `HandleCheckedChanged` function.  In the latter you are actually passing the DOM element.

You should change the first to:

```
var chkCtrl = $(this).find("td input:checkbox").get(0);
```